# How can I update all rows of a table based on the values of another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
// requests
+----+----------------+----------------+-------------+
| id | user_id        |      ip        |  unix_time  |
+----+----------------+----------------+-------------+
| 1  | 12353          | NULL           | 1339412843  |
| 2  | 12353          | NULL           | 1339412864  |
| 3  | NULL           | 178.253.29.175 | 1339412894  |
| 4  | 3422           | NULL           | 1339412899  |
| 5  | 3422           | NULL           | 1339412906  |
| 6  | 3422           | NULL           | 1339412906  |
| 7  | NULL           | 148.23.29.109  | 1339413640  |
| 8  | NULL           | 148.23.29.109  | 1339413621  |
| 9  | 5462           | NULL           | 1339414490  |
| 10 | NULL           | 178.253.29.175 | 1339419901  |
| 11 | 8007           | NULL           | 1339424860  |
| 12 | 8007           | NULL           | 1339424822  |
| 13 | 12353          | NULL           | 1339424902  |
| .  | .              | .              | .           |
| .  | .              | .              | .           |
| .  | .              | .              | .           |
+----+----------------+----------------+-------------+
```

Also I have this table:

```
// per_days
+----+---------+--------------+----------------+-----------------+--------------+
| id | user_id |  AllVisited  | MaxConsecutive | LastConsecutive | request_numb |
+----+---------+--------------+----------------+-----------------+--------------+
| 1  | 12353   | 43           | 8              | 3               | 47           |
| 2  | 3422    | 530          | 130            | 32              | 100          |
| .  | .       | .            | .              | .               | .            |
| .  | .       | .            | .              | .               | .            |
| .  | .       | .            | .              | .               | .            |
+----+---------+--------------+----------------+-----------------+--------------+
-- each user has one row into this ^ table (I mean user_id column is unique)
```

---

I need a query to select all rows from `requests` table which are in last day (I'll execute that query every day by an *event*) and then updates all rows of `per_days` table (for each user separately). Something like this:

```
UPDATE 
     per_days AS p
JOIN requests AS r
ON   p.user_id = r.user_id
SET  p.AllVisited      = p.AllVisited + IF( /* there is a row */, 1, 0),
     p.MaxConsecutive  = IF( p.LastConsecutive > p.MaxConsecutive, LastConsecutive, MaxConsecutive),    
     p.LastConsecutive = IF( /* there is a row */, p.LastConsecutive + 1, 1),
     p.request_numb    = { /* count(1) - the number of all requests (all selected rows) for specific user in this day */ }
WHERE r.unix_time > subdate(now(), interval '1' day)
```

How can I fix my query?

Comment: The first problem is that you have a JOIN statement but not actually joining the two tables together.(i.e. p.user_id = r.user_id)  Maybe it would be easier to start by breaking the UPDATE statement into 4 separate UPDATE statements.  Then you can create the joins and conditions for each metric.  Then later try to make it a single UPDATE.

Comment: @RickS Good point, I've edited.

Comment: You don't need the first `IF`. If there's no matching row, nothing will be joined.

Comment: @Barmar You are right. Thank you

Comment: @Barmar may you please write an answer ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join with a subquery that returns all the user IDs in `requests` in the time range. Use `LEFT JOIN`, and then your `if there's a row` test becomes `r.user_id IS NOT NULL`.

```
UPDATE 
     per_days AS p
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT user_id
    FROM requests 
    WHERE unix_time > subdate(now(), interval '1' day)) AS r
ON   p.user_id = r.user_id
SET  p.AllVisited      = p.AllVisited + IF(r.user_id IS NOT NULL, 1, 0),
     p.MaxConsecutive  = IF( p.LastConsecutive > p.MaxConsecutive, LastConsecutive, MaxConsecutive),    
     p.LastConsecutive = IF(r.user_id IS NOT NULL, p.LastConsecutive + 1, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you .. upvote. You know what `AllVisited` suppose to be? That will be `++` per day if the user has any activity on that day. So I think this `p.AllVisited + IFNULL(r.count, 0)` should be `p.AllVisited + IF(r.count, 1, 0),`. Am I right?

Comment: Your original code was joining with each row and didn't group, so I thought you wanted to add 1 for each row that was matched.

Comment: And my last question: actually I don't care about `request_numb` column and I can ignore it *(because seems it needs one more join just to count the rows)*. So may you please add your query without working on `request_numb` column? Suppose there isn't `request_numb` at all.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just I don't know why you said `LEFT JOIN` in your explanations and you've used `JOIN` in the query.

Comment: Hah .. You are pretty fast .. I'm impressed.

Comment: As a note, can I use `LIMIT 1` instead of `DISTINCT`? Because as you know I just need one row from `requests` tabale for each user.

Comment: No, `LIMIT 1` means 1 total row, not 1 per user. Use either `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY user_id`.